# In Keras, what is a "dense" and a "dropout" layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, transfer-learning

what is the main difference between dense and dropout layers in Keras

Answer (score 5):

In short, a dropout layer ignores a set of neurons (randomly) as one can see in the picture below. This normally is used to prevent the net from overfitting.

The Dense layer is a normal fully connected layer in a neuronal network. [image]

Resources:

[Improving neural networks by preventing co-adaptation of feature detectors](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0580)

[Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from Overfitting](http://jmlr.org/papers/v15/srivastava14a.html)

[A Gentle Introduction to Dropout for Regularizing Deep Neural Networks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/)

Let me know if you need a more precise explanation.